# How to check whether the dictionary exixts or not in Iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an Iphone application in which i am adding values to an array from a dictionary.can anybody tell me how i can check whether the dictionary exists or not before iterating in it?

```
NSDictionary *news=[dict objectForKey:@"news"];
NSDictionary *deals=[dict objectForKey:@"deals"];
NSLog(@"%@",[news classForCoder]);
NSLog(@"%@",news);
NSLog(@"%@",deals);

for(NSDictionary *key in news)
{
    if([key isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {        
        [dataArray addObject:key]; 
    }
    // NSLog(@"%@",rewardsId);
    //[dataArray addObject:dictrewards];
}

for(NSDictionary *key in deals)
{      
    if([key isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {  
        [dataArray1 addObject:key];       
    }

    // NSLog(@"%@",rewardsId);
    //[dataArray addObject:dictrewards];
}

self.newsseperatearray=dataArray;
self.dealsseperatearray=dataArray1;

self.newssarray = [[dataArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:dataArray1] mutableCopy];

NSLog(@"%@",self.newssarray);
//self.newssarray=dataArray;
[self.mTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Naming a dictionary 'key' is confusing! Also, your code has too many new lines.

Comment: is `news` an array of `NSDictionary` instances?

Comment: why do you want to check it before? if it is not exists (aka `nil`) the iteration won't be started and it won't cause any problem for you. but for your sake before the iteration you could check the pointer is a valid one or `nil`.

Comment: This is correct; In Objective-C, nil is 'safe' (messages to nil are ignored). Also, being non-nil doesn't guarantee that the object is what you'd expect. It might even be a zombie.

Answer (score 1):

You should check that it is not nil and that it actually is a NSDictionary

```
if(news && [news isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    do stuff
}
```